# Is there any way to break the character limit in forms on websites?

Tags: website

I'm trying to enter my address on a website that has a character limit for the address and I cannot type in the whole thing. Is it possible to extend this with an extension or something?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what is imposing the limit.  If it is JavaScript, disabling it in your browser might work, or modifying the element in your browser.  If it is a `maxlength` attribute, you might be able to modify the element in your browser.  If its a server side script, you are out of luck.

However, it seems odd that a field meant to take an IP address cant.  What format of IP address are you using and what is it expecting?

Comment: Just a guess, but this sounds like it might be a "normal" (e.g. home or business) address rather than an IP address (unless it's IPv6?).